# retrieve documents after grouping search in lucene

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, grouping

I am doing lucene search on my resources.I have a case where I search for a particular product and I need to do it on a grouping search via 'keywords' field.I can get to know the total number of products grouped by keywords associated with it.How can I get all the documents related to this search, so that I can retrieve other needed fields from it. I tried using AbstractAllGroupHeadsCollector but couldnt find and got confused with its usage.Here is my code. 
Thanks in advance.

```
        Integer totalGroupCount = null;
        IndexReader ir = DirectoryReader.open(indexLocation);
        IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(ir);
        GroupingSearch groupingSearch = new GroupingSearch("keywords");
        groupingSearch.setGroupSort(Sort.RELEVANCE);
        groupingSearch.setFillSortFields(true);
        groupingSearch.setCachingInMB(4.0, true);
        groupingSearch.setAllGroups(true);
        //TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("products", "wfa packages"));
        TopGroups<BytesRef> result = groupingSearch.search(is, query, 0, 10);
        // Render groupsResult...
        totalGroupCount = result.totalGroupCount; // The group count
        GroupDocs<BytesRef>[] d=result.groups;
        System.out.println("total groups="+result.totalGroupedHitCount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `GroupDocs` array, that's most of the way there already.  You can then get the `scoreDocs` from each GroupDocs, and lookup the document with the doc id, from `ScoreDoc.doc`, like:

```
for (GroupDocs<BytesRef> group : d) {
    for (ScoreDoc scoredoc : group.scoreDocs) {
        Document doc = is.doc(scoredoc.doc);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```